# Retrive Sales Data through API for sales from POS

Tags: square, square-connect

I am trying to do some custom analytics and analysis for my business. We use the Square POS, and have access to the API. I can retrieve the transactions, but cannot seem to get the Order ID's that I need to batch retrieve the orders. What am I missing? Is it possible through the API to access the same sales data that I can see in my dashboard?

Comment: It may be useful for you to know that the V2 API adds to (not replaces) the V1 API, according to a comment on another SO question. I haven't seen this mentioned on the Square website though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you are looking for. Items that are sold? Try the v1Payments endpoint. The order's endpoint that you are using is for primarily for pulling the transaction data from e-commerce transactions.

Comment: He's looking for orders, not payments, as he says